# Swift3 how to catch all exceptions?

Tags: ios, swift3, error-handling, exception

I'm debugging a table view in Swift3 and it complains about the number of rows. Because I know of no way to catch this exception, I'm forced to re-launch the project every time.

**How do I catch swift exceptions which do not throw errors, like the table view example below?**

```
   do { 
      self.tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .left)

   } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
```

Does not work:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: You are asking about something different, but this error occurs when you try to insert/delete rows on the `tableView` but you forget to update the backing model accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

that's basically an NSError from objective-c world, which are different and unrelated to swift Exceptions.